# Django custom error handling when the url supplied does not match with any URL in ROOT_URLCONF

Tags: django, root, custom-error-handling, urlconf

How can I send a custom error message to front end when the endpoint coming from front end does not match with any URL in ROOT_URLCONF in settings.py. Currently if URL is not found in ROOT_URLCONF, a 403 error is raised and the entire html content is going in the error message.

How to send a custom error message in this case.

Comment: *a 403 error is raised* - are you sure you don't mean 404?

Comment: What about [custom error views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views) ?

Comment: Note that you need to set `DEBUG=False` to see the actual 404 response. When `DEBUG=True`, Django will show the yellow debug 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a custom error handler function returning a json string

```
def not_found_request(request, exception, *args, **kwargs):
"""
Generic 404 error handler.
"""
data = {
    'error': 'The requested endpoint does not exist'
}
return JsonResponse(data, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Then in your urlconf file you can set it to `handler404 = 'not_found_request'`

Comment: what is urlconf file?

Comment: I have added the method in the view file and set handler404 = 'not_found_request' in settings.py file after ROOT_URLCONF. I am getting error message in console: stack: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1↵    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)↵    at XMLHttpRequest.s ...
message: "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1"